# how to builde .exe for a pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

Hi I would like to know if I can transform my PyQt code to `.exe`.
I know someone said before to use pyinstaller but that did not worked for me I am trying this:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile myscript.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you `cd` to the correct directory, which may be something like C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe, and then run the command - or, you can include the full path itself when you run the command. Also, I wouldn't have extra spaces between the `--onefile--` and `myscript.py`.

Comment: No problem at all